# Select element not working properly with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, select, grid

The title. I've managed to align 2 divs side by side using grid, thats fine, but as soon as the content of the second div is a select element, the second div is for some reason shorter, how can I fix that?

**CSS**

```
.inputwrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'halfl halfr';
    grid-column-gap: 2%;
}
.input50r{
    grid-area: halfr;
    display:  grid;
}
.input50l{
    grid-area: halfl;
    display:  grid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='input50l'>
  <input type='password' name='encKey' placeholder='Password' />
</div>
<div class='input50r'>
  <select>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nokO.png)

The select element has no special styling, just cosmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inputwrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'halfl halfr';
    grid-column-gap: 2%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Can u explain why? And why is the select element misbehaving?

Comment: I don't know why for sure, but I suspect that everything is using content based widths unless you force it